# glacier php expedited download

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am trying to download my archive from Amazon Glacier using expedited option. I'm doing it via PHP with PHP SDK3. I have a little problem. I've launched job to get ArchiveID:

```
$credentials = new Credentials('GLA_AWS_KEY', 'GLA_AWS_SECRET');


$client = new GlacierClient(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region'  => 'GLA_AWS_REGION'
));

$result = $client->initiateJob(array(
    'vaultName' => 'GLA_AWS_VAULT',
    'jobParameters' => [
        'Type' => 'archive-retrieval',
        'ArchiveId' => $archiveId,
    ]
));
$jobid = $result->get('jobId');
```

How can you recover the file in expedited mode?

Thanx for any help ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. For anyone interested on it.

```
$result = $client->initiateJob(array(
    'vaultName' => 'GLA_AWS_VAULT',
    'jobParameters' => [
        'Type' => 'archive-retrieval',
        'ArchiveId' => $archiveId,
        'Tier' => 'Expedited'
    ]
));
```

We need to add the Tier as Expedited. The download time reduces to 5 minuts more or less.